# How to find if web page got appended using chrome extension

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, onupdate

I am new to chrome extension and I am trying to find whether page content got appended.

For E.g. in Facebook, we can see the content will appended automatically when the user scroll down the page.

I have the following code in background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

   alert("page is appending....");

});
```

The above code is expected to fire when the page got updated. But, I am seeing that it is getting called only for few times. Not always.

Or Am I making any mistake here ?

My requirement is, whenever the web page appended in facebook, I have to do get the page content and obtain few string from the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define better what you mean by "appending". If you mean that the DOM changes, you need to have a content script watching for that. `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` only fires when the tab changes (normally on navigation), not the page content.

Comment: Yes, I meant by DOM content only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *onUpdated* event is in the chrome.tabs namespace on purpose, it listens the updates of tab's general attributes like: the tab pinned, the favicon changed, the URL changed, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) (also check the update() method). So this way is not workable. Instead listen the DOM tree change with **DOMSubtreeModified** event or **MutationObserver**.

Comment: A good guide to link to is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener). Maybe edit that in? Otherwise, your response is correct.